# nav_msgs Path: is it possible to separate the visualized trajectories?

Tags: ros, rviz, path, ros-kinetic, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using the `nav_msgs::Path` message to visualize multiple trajectories.

**With one path publisher!**

I want to separate these trajectories, i mean, i don't want them to be connected with the line when its visualized in `RViz`.

Is it possible to break somehow the visualized path?

I tried to solve it by adding a dummy pose of x,y,z=nan, but that did not work, since `RVIZ` couldn't visualize the path due to Nans.

I also tried to change the `frame_id` of the dummy pose, but  that resulted in basically a xyz=0 (a 2 lines were drawn to 000 in rviz).

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328845/nav_msgs-path:-is-it-possible-to-separate-the-visualized-trajectories?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
That's not what `nav_msgs::Path` is designed for so it won't work. You can do this with a `geometry_msgs::Marker` LINE_LIST type. Or you could use multiple publishers of `nav_msgs::Path`

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-07-18**:
Thank you. Could you put this into an answer? I will accept it.

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-07-18**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd it turns out that the `LINE_STRIP` is the one i need to use for path visualization. But still i don't understand how should i "break"/separate the paths? Suppose i have the following points for two trajectories:

x , y, z

1, 0, 0 <- traj1, point1

1, 1, 0 <- traj1, point2

0, 1, 0 <- traj1, point3

BREAK/SEPARATION IS REQUIRED HERE

-1, 1, 0 <- traj2, point1

-1, 0, 0 <- traj2, point2

-1, -1, 0 <- traj2, point3

how can i separate traj1 and traj2 with the `geometry_msgs::Marker LINE_STRIP?`

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
That's why I recommended the LIST_LIST type. You will need to double up the points within each path, to make them continuous, but that means you can also represent unconnected paths within the same message.

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-07-18**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd

OKay then, im working on it. Thank you.

Should i copy your comment into the answer section?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
Yes, feel free to add that if you write up an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is based on the comment of @PeteBlackerThe3rd.

```
visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
```

should be used for the visualization of multiple/separated trajectories.
The points in the path should be doubled up to make them look continuous.

---

Originally posted by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) with karma: 121 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0